# Get purches from Google play by specific user

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I want to trace purchase by specific user. Is there way  to get purchases for user that is loged in app, not on device?
In documentation says:

"The Google Play service returns only the purchases made by the user account that is currently logged in to the device. If the request is successful, the returned Bundle has a response code of 0. The response Bundle also contains a list of the product IDs, a list of the order details for each purchase, and the signatures for each purchase."

Maybe to use Manager Account?

Any help is usefull. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If user successfully purchased and consume the result, then that user can purchase again. If you want to get purchases for user that is signed in app, not on device, you can save that state in your own server when purchase successfully.

Comment: So, I can not get informations from google play service about purchase for  user that is signed in app?

Comment: yes, because google play service is bind for google account not for app account